# AsyncTask with multiple tag parsing error

Tags: android, parsing, runtime-error, jsoup

```
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            // Locate the content attribute
            Elements h3Tag = document.select("h3");

            desc1 = Integer.toString(h3Tag.size());
            if(Integer.parseInt(desc1)==1)
            {                
                Element description = document.getElementsByTag("table").get(3);
            }
```

In the above code, whenever i add the line

`document.getElementByTag("table").get(3));`

The program crashes.. however if i remove the h3tag select it will work fine.. only one of them will work at a time not both..help?

log

```
 01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at org.jsoup.select.Elements.get(Elements.java:501)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at com.example.scrapping.MainActivity$Description.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:132)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at com.example.scrapping.MainActivity$Description.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966):  ... 4 more
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966): Activity com.example.scrapping.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d42af0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-772,216} that was originally added here
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.scrapping.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d42af0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-772,216} that was originally added here
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at com.example.scrapping.MainActivity$Description.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:116)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at com.example.scrapping.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:55)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-12 16:33:29.355: E/WindowManager(966):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-12 16:33:31.285: I/Process(966): Sending signal. PID: 966 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3 . index starts from 0 size is 3 that means its 0,1 and 2. you are accessing index 3

Comment: hey...thanks ya.. used wrong condition.. :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a bad index.. try 1 or 2 because you have this exception:

```
01-12 16:33:26.314: E/AndroidRuntime(966): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
```

Comment: Please consider explaining the answer a little.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you figured this out by now but I will post an explanation for future reference:

The error is an [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html) caused by the following line (specifically the `get(3)` part):

```
Element description = document.getElementsByTag("table").get(3);
```

According to the log output, the size of `description` is 3. That is, only 3 `<table>` elements exist in the HTML document your are parsing. Keeping in mind that index numbering begins at zero, 3 is an invalid index. That is, only 0, 1, and 2 are valid indexes for an ArrayList of size 3.

The reason your code will work when you remove the `Elements h3Tag = document.select("h3");` line is because without this, the condition of the if-statement is not satisfied so it won't run the code within.